# Chai Unit Testing Error

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write a unit test for the following file named **a.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/getHCQ', function (req, res) {
  res.send("OK");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Unit test file : **a.spec.js**

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var should = chai.should();

var a = require('./a');

describe('Unit Test', function () {
it('should run this', function (done) {
    chai.request(a)
        .get('/getHCQ')
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I am running it using **Mocha** but getting the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
  at Immediate.<anonymous> (node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:14)
```

Can someone please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is better to use `superagent` library to test the express APIs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal With `superagent` also, I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to configure `chai` with `chai-http`

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp); // <-- add this

var a = require('./a');

describe('Unit Test', function () {
it('should run this', function (done) {
    chai.request(a)
        .get('/getHCQ')
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```